# Analogous to tcpkill for IP over InfiniBand

Tags: networking, infiniband

Does anybody know if there is an equivalent tool to `tcpkill` for killing TCP connections that travel over Infiniband?
At the moment, when I use an infiniband interface, `tcpkill` complains:

```
# tcpkill -i ib0 port 12345
tcpkill: unsupported datalink type
tcpkill: couldn't determine link layer offset
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: tcpkill comes from dsniff package. In the source I have found the problem in pcaputil.c. Adding support for DLT_IPOIB, DLT_IPV4 and DLT_IPV6 and correct offset is likely to fix tcpkill regarding IPoIB.

Comment: BTW, this is not InfiniBand over IP (iWRAP), but IP over InfiniBand (IPoIB).

Comment: In fact it is likely DLT_LINUX_SLL given tcpdump output.

Comment: @ydroneaud yes, it was IPoIB (thanks Roland for the correction)

Comment: it's 2020 and still have the same problem. Any alternative commands/tool at least?